# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android

I am displaying 2 separate tables in a screen.
There is no problem displaying the first table.
Referring to TableLayout **second_table**  , TableRow **tableRow5** , Textfield(s) **textView51 , textView52 , textView53**

TextFields are basically the columns. Three columns to be displaying 
First Name , Last Name , Age.I need to dynamically set the values after fetching that from the server.

I am facing the following exception:
**java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.**

I am populating the second table using the following lines of code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.employee_details);
 TableLayout tableLay = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.second_table);
 TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tableRow5);
 TextView fNameTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView51);
 TextView lNameTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView52);
 TextView ageTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView53);
 for(int count = 0; count < tempArrList.size() ; count++){
 fNameTxtView.setText(tempArrList.get(temp.get(0)));
 lNameTxtView.setText(tempArrList.get(temp.get(1)));
 ageTxtView.setText(tempArrList.get(temp.get(2)));
  tableRow.addView(fNameTxtView);
  tableRow.addView(lNameTxtView);
  tableRow.addView(ageTxtView);
  tableLay.addView(tableRow); // Add the new row to our tableLayout
 }
}
```

I have tried few variations too ,  but unable to solve the problem.
Any suggestions welcome.

The layout xml follows:
**employee_details.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include android:id="@+id/header" layout="@layout/activity_header" />
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:background="@drawable/footerbg" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_width="150dp" android:id="@+id/btn_done"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView01"
        android:layout_above="@id/RelativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/header">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/hello_TxtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/first_table"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/table_shape">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView11"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView12"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
            <TableLayout android:id="@+id/second_table"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView41"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView42"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView43"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#f6f7fc">
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView51"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView52"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView53"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </TextView>
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `for` statement you are using the same `TextView` and `TableRow` objects and every time you do :

```
tableRow.addView(fNameTxtView);
  tableRow.addView(lNameTxtView);
  tableRow.addView(ageTxtView);
  tableLay.addView(tableRow);
```

you insert in your layout the same `TextView`s fNameTxtView, lNameTxtView, ageTxtView.
To avoid this you could create objects dynamically in your for statement like this:

```
for(int count = 0; count < tempArrList.size() ; count++){
TextView fNameTxtView = new TextView(this);
 fNameTxtView.setText(tempArrList.get(temp.get(0)));
TextView lNameTxtView= new TextView(this);
 lNameTxtView.setText(tempArrList.get(temp.get(1)));
TextView ageTxtView = new TextView(this);
 ageTxtView.setText(tempArrList.get(temp.get(2)));
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
  tableRow.addView(fNameTxtView);
  tableRow.addView(lNameTxtView);
  tableRow.addView(ageTxtView);
  tableLay.addView(tableRow); // Add the new row to our tableLayout
 }
```

edit: of course you could add IDs for the TextViews if you want do more work on them.